# Why is this programming question put on Hold?

Tags: support, questions, on-hold

[Learn Flutter or iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652434/learn-flutter-or-ios)

Answering this question requires opinions indeed, but also technical skills and experience. When we provide a solution to a programming problem, it also requires opinion to decide between the best approach to solve the problem. Requiring an opinon does not mean the question is not programming related.

This kind of question and their answers can help many students, developers, or even architects in choosing the right language for their project.

On stackoverflow.com, we should be able to exchange on programming topics other than the usual "Here is my code... please fix it"

Comment: Can it help many people?  Sure.  But before it manages to do that, it'll go through arguments about which is better, what will be the future, what pays more, etc., etc.  By the time the argument ends, one or the other, or both, will be dead, and the next argument about the next languages will begin.

Comment: It's not a bad question. It's simply inappropriate for the site and its rules. If what you suggest is that we should change the rules to allow this type of question... no thanks. It comes now and then, the the consensus is firmly against that, luckily.

Comment: I think providing answers to @Le Stradic Paul would help him making the best choice, even if it requires reading many answers

Comment: The objective of the site is not to help **one** user, but all future visitors. And again, is not about the question being helpful or not, but about being appropriate for the site. This site has rules.

Comment: Not every question that can be considered helpful is appropriate here. When I see questions that would benefit from a good discussion, I often point people to Reddit's `r/learnprogramming`. They have tight rules as well, but they allow for more open ended, opinionated questions.

Comment: This is why God invented opinion-based sites. As already stated, this site is not good for this type of question, but that doesn't mean that it can't be asked elsewhere on sites that welcome this such as Quora.

Comment: Go to any forum where such a question is allowed, ask "Should I use language X or should I use language Y?" - I am very sure you get a large portion voting for language X, a large portion voting for language Y and a small portion voting for language A,B,C,D and Z because X and Y suck according to them. Then what? Opinions offered by complete strangers are *terrible* for decision making, there are too many of them. Ask someone you know and trust. One person, maybe two. Not dozens of people.

Answer (score 5):

The question is very Opinion oriented and could attract all kind of answer, and none of the possible answers would actually make more sense than another. In fact, these kinds of questions could get ENDLESS answers; we don't want that. OP could go either way with his work, he could start over, finish what has been already done.

There is no possible neat working solution to be displayed.

Comment: Choosing the most appropriate language for a project is not easy. Especially nowdays with so many languages available. I think stackoverflow.com is an appropriate place to get help for this type of question.

Comment: @matdev It is not, because we don't allow them.  Experts stick around here because we don't allow such questions; if you allow them, experts will leave, and you'll lose the very reason you want to ask them.

Comment: Even as an expert in one language, there are some other projects where I'd be glad to get help choosing the most appropriate language. Where should I go then to ask this kind of questions ?

Comment: @matdev Quora, reddit, twitter, or any type of open forum type site.

Comment: OP's concern is rather unique and HIGHLY related to his situation, and thus not likely to help others